# Why my button component submits the form it is in?

Tags: javascript, forms, ember.js

If I put a button inside a form and click on it, only the button-click event is triggered.

But if I build a button component "my-button", replace the button with "my-button" and click on it again, it triggers the button click event but also submits the form.

Is it supposed to behave that way? How do I make my component not submit the form?

```js
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  actions: {
    clicked: function() {
      alert('click');
    },
    submitted: function() {
      alert('submit');
    }
  }
});

App.MyButtonComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  tagName: "button",
  click: function() {
    this.sendAction();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script><script src="http://builds.emberjs.com/tags/v1.11.1/ember-template-compiler.js"></script><script src="http://builds.emberjs.com/tags/v1.11.1/ember.debug.js"></script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars">
    <form {{action "submitted" on="submit" }}>
        {{my-button action="clicked"}}
        <button {{action "clicked"}}>button</button>
    </form>
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="components/my-button">
    my-button
</script>
```

I also created a [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/mibomayawu/edit?console,output). Any click event logs “click” to the console and a form submit logs “submit” into the browser console.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and **the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you aren't specifying the type of button, and by default the button type is "submit", which then submits your action. You can change this by specifying the button type in your component.

```
App.MyButtonComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  tagName: "button",

  attributeBindings: ['type'],
  click: function(){
    this.sendAction();
  }
});
```

Now, when specifying your form, you can tell your component what type of button it should be.

```
inside form: {{my-button action="clicked" type="button"}}
```

http://jsbin.com/zutacipido/2/edit